# MySQL JOIN with count / distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got multiple tables in my database.

Below is my SQL. It all works well for the majority.

How my system works is I may have a game which may sit in multiple competitions therefore will get called into this query more than once through the various JOINS.

It's like Liverpool playing a game but that game earns points for two competitions. It's not two games even though it'll appear twice. It's also not two rows in my database table 'game'.

What I have works for everything but the games that are in two competitions and where I want to do a few counts.

So my query code at the bottom works, but if I try add in

```
SUM(CASE WHEN g.isRanfurly = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TTLTests,
```

then this fails as it counts those games twice.

Any ideas?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(g.gameId), gd.playerId, t.teamName, 

COUNT(distinct gd.gameId) as Appearances,
SUM(gd.tries) as TTLTries,

COUNT(CASE WHEN g.isTestMatch = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TTLTests,

IF(gd.homeaway = 1, g.team1Id, g.team2Id) as myteamId
  
FROM `gamedata` gd

JOIN `games` g ON gd.gameId = g.gameId
JOIN `teams` t ON t.teamId = IF(gd.homeaway = 1, g.team1Id, g.team2Id)
JOIN `roundgames` rg ON rg.gameId = gd.gameId
JOIN `rounds` r ON r.roundId = rg.roundId
JOIN `competitions` c ON r.competitionId = c.competitionId
        
WHERE `playerId` = 1 AND `didntPlay` = 0 AND t.teamType = 2

group by t.teamName
```

Comment: Please share some sample data and expected output.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result as tabular text

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT g.gameId, gd.playerId, t.teamName ...` to make code clearer.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: As for expected output. fields (playerId, teamName, appearances, ttltries, ttltests, myteamId) = (1747, 'Broncos', 30, 20, 34). ttl tests would be lower as some of those games are played in multiple competitions.  If I remove the last 4 joins it works correctly but JUST counting the gamedata table. But then I can't get data from these which I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below - remove the `else 0` from the `conditional count`

```
SELECT gd.playerId, t.teamName, 
COUNT(distinct gd.gameId) as Appearances,
SUM(gd.tries) as TTLTries,
COUNT(CASE WHEN g.isTestMatch = 1 THEN 1 END) as TTLTests,
IF(gd.homeaway = 1, g.team1Id, g.team2Id) as myteamId
FROM `gamedata` gd
JOIN `games` g ON gd.gameId = g.gameId
JOIN `teams` t ON t.teamId = IF(gd.homeaway = 1, g.team1Id, g.team2Id)
JOIN `roundgames` rg ON rg.gameId = gd.gameId
JOIN `rounds` r ON r.roundId = rg.roundId
JOIN `competitions` c ON r.competitionId = c.competitionId
WHERE `playerId` = 1 AND `didntPlay` = 0 AND t.teamType = 2
group by gd.playerId, t.teamName
```

Comment: Thanks, that's super close but I get two rows for teamName with different game Id's

Comment: @Jason, check the answer now

Comment: These two lines work, but I can't do a SUM using the same logic COUNT(DISTINCT gd.gameId) as Appearances,
COUNT(DISTINCT g.gameId, CASE WHEN g.isRanfurly = 1 THEN 1 END) as TTLTests,

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use DISTINCT within the SUM

```
SUM(CASE WHEN g.isTestMatch = 1 THEN gd.tries ELSE 0 END) as TTLTestTries,
```